# Как вывести имена всех участников чата

Tags: python, telebot

Я хочу создать телеграм бота на пайтоне, который будет выводить имена всех учасников чата, при использовании команды. Можете подсказать, как сделать, чтобы этот бот находил всех учасников чата?

Comment: Очень интересно, как Вы себе представляете ответ на свой вопрос? Ну так тезисно можете описать?

Comment: Я не эксперт, но по моему это прямой заказ, а не вопрос.

Comment: Простите, возможно немного неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Я просто хотел узнать команду для узнавания всех участников.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода количества участников

```
tb.get_chat_members_count(chat_id)
```

Для вывода админов

```
tb.get_chat_administrators(chat_id)
```

Для получения пользователя

```
tb.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
```

Comment: А как узнать id всех пользователей чата?

Comment: @РадикГусєв этого нет в официальной документации. Как вариант можно отслеживать вход\сообщения пользователей и записывать их в базу данных. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api